# R: Writing a recursive function for a Random Walk (initial values)

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion

I'm a new user to R, and I am trying to create a function that will simulate a random walk. The issue for me is trying to integrate some initial values smoothly. Say I have this basic function.

```
y(t) = y(t-2) + eps(t)
```

Epsilon (or eps(t)) will be the randomness factor. I want to define y(-1)=0, and y(0)=0.

Here is my code:

```
ran.walk=function(n){       # 'n' steps will be the input
    eps=rnorm(n)            # creates a vector taking random values from N(0,1)
    y= c(eps[1], eps[2])    # this will set up my initial vector
    for (i in 3:n){
        ytemp = y[i-2] + eps[i] ## !!! problem is here. Details below !!!
        y= c(y, ytemp)
    }
    return(y)
}
```

I'm trying to get this start adding y3, y4, y5, etc, but I think there is a flaw in this design... I'm not sure if I should just set up two separate lines, with an if statement: testing if n is even or odd, perhaps with:

```
if i%%2 == 1   #using modulus
```

Since,

```
y1= eps1,
y2= eps2,
y3= y1 + eps3,
y4= y2 + eps4,
y5= y3 + eps5  and so on...
```

Currently, I see the error in my code.
I have y1, and y2 concatenated, but I don't think it knows how to incorporate y[1]
Can I define beforehand somehow y[-1]=0, and y[0]=0 ? I tried this also and got an error.

Thank you kindly in advance for any assistance. This is first times attempting a for loop with recursion.

-N  (sorry for any formatting issues, I had a lot of problems getting this question to go through)

Comment: I think `y= c(err[1], eps[2])` should be `y= c(eps[1], eps[2])`

Comment: My apologies, I use "error" and "epsilon" interchangeably as a habit from regression.

As a side note, I believe that splitting the for loop with an if statement after does the trick (perhaps not the most elegant).

That is:
    if (i%%2==1) #then use eps[1] as initial value
    else # for even numbers, using eps[2] as initial values, the vector concatenates just the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that your odd and even series is independent one of the other. Assuming that it is the case, I just split the problem in two columns and use `cumsum` to get the random walk. The final data frame include the random numbers and the random walk, so you can compare it is working properly.
Hoping it helps

```
ran.walk=function(n) {
  eps=rnorm(ceiling(n / 2)*2)
  dim(eps) <- c(2,ceiling(n/2))
  # since each series is independent, we can tally each one in its own
  eps2 <- apply(eps, 1, cumsum)
  # and just reorganize it
  eps2 <- as.numeric(t(eps2))
  rndwlk <- data.frame(rnd=as.numeric(eps), walk=eps2)
  # remove the extra value if needed
  rndwlk <- rndwlk[1:n,]
  return(rndwlk)
}
ran.walk(13)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is always good to see an alternative method. I will check this as the best answer as my thanks (can't give up votes yet I suppose to deter alternate account creation).

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break with my piano, it came to me. It's funny how simple the answer becomes once you discover it... almost trivial.

Setting the initial value to be a vector, that is:

```
[y(1) = y(-1) + eps(1), y(2)= y(0) + eps(2)]
```

everything works out. It is still true that the evens and odds don't interact, but there is no reason to specify any of that.

The method to split the iterations with modulus, then concatenating it back into the main vector would also work, but is unnecessary and more complicated. Shorter is better for users and computers. As Einstein said, make it as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: Good that you found a solution! Just keep in mind that R's strength is managing vectors. In small applications you will not see any difference, but it is still useful to try to work with vectors (for instance using `cumsum`) when possible.